# Getting an error while calling the calling back arguement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

Here is my code:

```
function getStatus(csrfToken, onSuccess) {
  $("#statusItemsList").html("");
  statusData = {};
  postData = {
    table: getArgs().table,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken
  };

  if (getArgs().table) {
    $.post(STATUS_URL, postData, function(data) {
      if (data.items.length < 1) {
        $("#statusTable").hide();
        $("#empty-status").show();
        onSuccess(null);
      } else {
        $("#empty-status").hide();
        $("#statusTable").show();
        for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
          statusData[data.items[i].itemId] = data.items[i].itemStatus;
        }
        onSuccess(statusData);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I call this function the console displays

> onSuccess is not a function

I am calling the function like:

```
getStatus("token", (data)=>{  });
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling `getStatus`? It sounds like you're not passing it a function...

Comment: The second argument must be a Function object. `getStatus('tokenHere', function(status) { //...status});`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am calling it like this:
    getStatus("token", (data)=>{});

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/8pwndj6v/; Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using babel? does your browser support es6? If not try to call your 'getstatus' function with a predefined function.

```
function func(){
//blah blah
}
    getstatus("token", func);
```

Comment: My browser does support es6. And no, I am not using babel. Your solution works, but why isn't (data)=>{}  working ?

Comment: i created a test utilizing arrow functions and they worked. if you are running your app in a browser that supports es6 then my only guess is that something is wrong with how the function is being read at runtime. you can console.log the type of your arrow function to make sure it is being viewed as a "Function". I am sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Solved. I was not calling it properly. Thanks.